# Is the probability of obtaining $HHHH$ lower than the probability of $HTHT$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume you toss a coin with the outcomes being Heads (H) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and Tails (T) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then the probability of obtaining the sequence $HHHH$ is $\frac{1}{2^4}$ which is equal to the probability of obtaining $HTHT$.

However, it seems strange to me that for example the two sequences:

$HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH$

and

$HTHTTTHTTHTTTHTTHT$

are equally probable with probability $\frac{1}{2^{18}}$

Doesn't the sequence observed so far influence the probabilities for the next coin toss? So, if you have already observed 10 heads in a row, it would be more likely that the next observation is tails.

Comment: You're saying that if I flipped a coin in front of you and it was heads 100 times, you'd expect tails the next time?

Comment: Is there a mathematical question here?

Comment: It is almost the definition of a fair coin - or follows straightforwardly from any sufficiently precise definition - that (a) any particular sequence of $n$ heads and tails is equally likely (there are $2^n$ such sequences, so if one is more likely, which is less likely?) (b) the outcome of any particular flip is independent of the outcome of any other flip.

Comment: Ever been to Vegas? All those pretty buildings were financed by guys with similar ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Making reasonable assumptions about the coin, one sequence is not more likely than the other. In practice, there will be certain biasing factors, such as the weighting of the coin, the person who flips it, and the orientation of the coin before it's flipped, but these are difficult to predict, and won't predictably influence a mix of heads and tails over all heads.

Think about it this way: what physical process corrects this? What force of the universe acts conditionally on our observing 18 heads in a row, and causes the next flip to more likely be tails?

The problem here, I think, is one of conditional probability. You've correctly identified that seeing 19 heads in a row is a tiny probability: $2^{-19}$. The same is true of any other sequence, but the property of having only one outcome is something that stands out to us humans.

However, the fact that this easily expressible outcome is so unlikely does not survive the given information. We already know that 18 heads were tossed in a row, a comparably unlikely result. Given this information, the chance of having 19 heads in a row is now probability of $2^{-1}$.